# Get cookie function always returns false

Tags: javascript, cookies

I have a function:

```
function check(cv) {
  return !!document.cookie.split(/;\s*/).filter(function (c) {
    return cv === c.split(/=/)[1]
  }).length;
}
```

that should return `true` or `false` depending on a cookie if it exists or not.

I have a sample code - https://jsfiddle.net/HillelNagid/bu4qboum/ that creates a cookie `mopened` and shows a modal dialog if the cookie doesn't exist, and if it does, the modal dialog is not shown.

The problem is that `check()` function returns `false` even though the cookie exists. I would want to know why is that?
It can be because the path of the cookie?

Answer (score 0):

You are taking 2nd index of array after split... change it to first index. 
change code as follow.

```
function check(cv) { 
    return !!document.cookie.split(/;\s*/).filter(function(c){
                return cv === c.split(/=/)[0]}).length; 
             }
```

as key will be in first part of split from  =

Comment: for me .. it's working... make sure cookie is properly set

Comment: to test paste this function in console and cookie in storage and then call this function  with same name as cookie key

Comment: even your fiddle is working fine.. see you wont get true first time.. as cookie is still not set ... run your fiddle second time .. you will get true and modal will not open ...

Comment: My fiddle is not working, if someone can fork my fiddle if it works for him, It will be great

Comment: I change the function to jquery function, this is not work too.https://jsfiddle.net/HillelNagid/bu4qboum/4/

Comment: jsfiddle has two different domains for cookies.

Comment: i try to do this in my localhost, this do it too

Comment: do you have a skype for speak faster? it for my work until end of sunday